# Binding three levels down in the data hierarchy

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

It's a good thing I don't mind feeling stupid.

I'm trying to bind to an ObservableCollection on my view model. The data hierarchy looks like: Parent -contains list of- Child objects. Nothing complicated.

At the outermost grid of my Xaml tree I establish a link to the view model with:

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource src}">
```

Yes, src does reference the view model and the two dozen bindings before the problem textbox work fine. There is not another DataContext in my Xaml tree. Now I come to a simple textbox. I want to bind Textbox text to a child.property.

This works:

```
  <TextBlock 
     DataContext="{Binding Parent}"
     Text="{Binding Path=Child.Property}"
     Style="{StaticResource headerMajor}"
  />
```

This doesn't work:

```
  <TextBlock 
     Text="{Binding Source=Parent,Path=Child.Property}"
     Style="{StaticResource headerMajor}"
  />
```

I thought they were two ways of saying the same thing. Ordinarily I wonder for a moment and then keep on coding. However, some advice I've read mentioned that DataContext attributes buried in Xaml controls can lead to hard to find bugs.

Please explain why one works and the other does not. This will help my grasp on the whole binding topic.

Jim

Comment: Please have a look at the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source.aspx) is a property which holds an `object` used as source for the binding, it does not resolve to a property. Hence your binding is looking for the property path `Child.Property` on the string `"Parent"`, see the problem?

Comment: So now Im confused. I thought I understood what that sentence meant. The Source I specified is an object that contains the child object. I obviously don't get it yet. All of my attempts to use the Source= part of the binding have always failed on this project. Please try one more time to explain what should be specified as Source= : view model? a parent? the child? If the answer is the view model, then how do I get to the child?

Comment: @user858233: You should only use the `Source` in very few cases, you really should read its documentation that i linked to, its main use case is binding to objects that are specified as resource using the `StaticResource` markup extension, e.g. `Source={StaticResource ColorResource}`. Here you can change the binding to only use a path `Parent.Child.Property` (which sounds a bit pointless though as that should be same as `Property`.

Comment: @user858233: Binding paths are always relative to a source, the implicit source if you do not specify anything else is the current `DataContext`, if you do specify a source the `DataContext` is not used. Sources are `Source`, `RelativeSource` and `ElementName`, pick one or none.

Comment: Sorry, missed the link in your answer. The fog is starting to lift. Does this sound correct? One of my Source= objects could be myViewModel. I could use that as a source, but I could not a property on myViewModel, like my "Parent" property. Does your first comment imply that the binding "engine" would walk down my data hierarchy to find "Property" two levels down?

Comment: @JimBoone: The source can be any object, it's also often used in code behind where you can do `binding.Source = this` or any other object for that matter, in XAML however everything you place there is interpreted as a string (unless it's another markup extension). You can create bindings with element syntax though, then you can for example create a source in place. My first comment was just a thought about the logical data structure, if you go up to the `Parent` then down to the `Child` (given there is only one) you should be where you started, hence the whole bit could be omitted.

Comment: Did this now answer your question or are giving up? I cannot really tell. If it did answer the question you could [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/).